# Android remove callbacks on postdelayed xml element

Tags: android

I have a code as below:

```
myelement.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        myelement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } }, 8000);
```

I want this to remove callback everytime onStop() or onPause() happens.

I read in other SO articles you could do:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(null);
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

When I tried to do:

```
public synchronized void onPause() {        // on pause
    myelement.removeCallbacks(null);
    super.onPause();                        
}
```

and tried to go back and forth between activities. When I tried to do this, however, the element just glitched like sometimes showing the element for half a second, sometimes a full second, sometimes it works. etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `removeCallback()` method takes a runnable, so you have to keep a reference to it.

e.g.:

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Demo";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;
    private View mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mView = findViewById(R.id.some_view);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        doSomethingInFiveSeconds();
    }

    void doSomethingInFiveSeconds() {
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Post Delayed!");

                if (mView != null) {
                    // Animate it… 
                    mView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(250);
                    // or just make it disappear
                    // mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }

        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Additionally, it's hard to tell what your view is doing because you haven't really shown much code. When in doubt, make sure your Handler is looping on the Main Thread (it is by default); I don't know what your `myelement` is.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Although it wasn't the exact solution, it did help me arrive at my optimal solution by validating some points for me. I also added the `mRunnable!=null` block from your suggestion to check for non null runnable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`myelement` is a layout element (LinearLayout in this case) which i need to have pop up at the start of the activity and disappear after some time, hence the use of a runnable.

I figured the reason the callbacks weren't working in the first place was because my runnable couldn't be referenced. So I did the following.

**Solution:**

Outside of `onCreate`, created a global variable:

```
private Runnable myRunnable;
```

...and changed the code block (in question above) to:

```
myelement.postDelayed(myRunnable = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { myelement.setVisibility(View.GONE); } 
}, 8000);
```

So that inside `onPause()` and `onStop()`, when I do:

```
public synchronized void onPause() {        
    if(myRunnable!=null){
        myelement.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

It will now correctly remove callbacks and I don't get the stuttering appearing and disappearing element anymore.